# Are the following functions (f and g) examples which are discontinuous at 1, though f x g is continuous at 1?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working though (on my own; and unfortunately I don't live near a university) a text on Real Analysis: Bartle and Sherbert, 4th Ed.  Chapter 5 is "Continuous Functions". In Section 5.2 ("Combinations of Continuous Functions") one of the exercises (#3, pp. 133) asks for functions ***f*** and ***g*** which are discontinuous at some point c in their shared domain, but when the functions are multiplied that function is continuous at the point c.

One of the difficulties in studying on my own is that -- for open-ended questions like this -- it is difficult to know if my own ideas are correct.  I understand the answer suggested in the book, and I think I understand the question.

However, I have no clear way of determining if MY idea is (also) correct.  I came up with the two functions:

***f***: = (e^(1/(1-x)))/(1-x)

***g***: = the reciprocal of   ***f***

Thus, when multiplied together, their product-function is the constant 1, and continuous at 1 (and elsewhere).  But each is discontinuous at the point x = 1.

Thus, I believe this answer is also correct?  Is it?

Thanks for taking the time to help me!  (I'm actively looking for a local tutor, as we're a large research-base oriented community and there are at least some mathematicians working here; but no luck so far...)

Comment: By "inverse" do you mean "reciprocal"?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Corrected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your $f$ is undefined at $1$, so it's neither continuous nor discontinuous there.

You can take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb Q\\2&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$and$$g(x)=\begin{cases}2&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb Q\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $f$ and $g$ are discontinuous everywhere, but $f\times g=2$.

Comment: Indeed, this was the answer the book had (or very similar).  Thanks!

Comment: And got it.  Thanks also.  I'll keep looking...!

Comment: The exponential, when in the denominator, accomplishes what I want, as it approaches the limiting value of 0 (at x = 1), but remains defined, right?  So I need another function that has this property, as the simple (1-x) is undefined at x=1.  Is that correct?

Comment: I cannot answer, because I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: And to make sure I'm understanding fully what you were saying: the term (1-x) in the denominator of function f is undefined at x=1, making f undefined at that point.  Is the numerator of that function also undefined at that point, because of the (1-x) term in the denominator of the power term?  Or is the numerator portion defined, as the limit is 1 as x-->1?  Thanks again. (I also note that I left off a part of the numerator term that I'd intended to insert, which would have been necessary for my attempt to work. But that is immaterial if the numerator is also undefined at 1.)

Comment: The expression $1-x$ is defined at $x=1$. But it is $0$ there, and therefore *any* expression of the type $\frac{f(x)}{1-x}$ is undefined at $x=1$.